# Best way to properly store data in a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm studying about JSON and its use cases. Suppose I have a recipe book and I have the following JSON to store recipes (I apologize if anything is wrong before hand, I'm just starting with this)

```
var recipeBook = 
{
    recipes: 
    [
        {
            name: 'Spaghetti',
            ingredients: 
            [
                {
                    ingredientName: 'Pasta',
                    requiredAmount: 1,
                },
                {
                    ingredientName: 'Tomato Sauce',
                    requiredAmount: 1,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            name: 'Cereal',
            ingredients:
            [
                {
                    ingredientName = 'Cereal Box',
                    requiredAmount = 1
                },
                {
                    ingredientName = 'Milk',
                    requiredAmount = '1'
                }
            ] 
        }
    ]
}
```

Say I wanted to add a third recipe, or add a new ingredient to a recipe...I'm wondering what is the best option (code-wise) to add new data into this JSON.

Comment: The only redundancy I can find (the rest is really fine) is the `recipes` Array. `recipeBook` should be an Array. The rest is easily googlable. What have you tried? What results have you tried for *"How to add an Object into Array"*? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: This is an object literal. Not really a true JSON object. Besides that it's hard to follow, are you wondering how to add a new recipe to this? You should look into instantiating objects. I'll write an example if not done so already.

Comment: One note, piggy backing off of @AtlanteAvila; JSON isn't to be confused with generic objects in JavaScript. JSON has stricter syntax requirements than generic JS objects do, including having all property names in double quotes (`"recipes":`). A description of the full spec is [here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First, JSON vs. JS Objects

JSON isn't to be confused with generic objects in JavaScript. JSON is a "[lightweight data-interchange format](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)" that does its best to be both easy for humans to read and edit, yet also easy for computers to parse and generate. One of the main differences is that JSON has stricter syntax requirements than generic JS objects do.

What you've written is simply an object declaration in Javascript, rather than standard JSON. A JSON equivalent to your example data would look like this:

```
{
  "recipes": [
    {
      "name": "Spaghetti",
      "ingredients": [
        {
          "ingredientName": "Pasta",
          "requiredAmount": 1
        },
        {
          "ingredientName": "Tomato Sauce",
          "requiredAmount": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Cereal",
      "ingredients": [
        {
          "ingredientName": "Cereal Box",
          "requiredAmount": 1
        },
        {
          "ingredientName": "Milk",
          "requiredAmount": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The specific distinctions here:

- All property names are enclosed in double quotes `"`
- All strings are enclosed in double quotes `"` rather than single `'`
- Trailing commas that aren't followed by another key/ value pair or data structure aren't allowed

You could choose to omit the `recipes` property and keep just the array without the enclosing object, this would still be valid.

Also worth noting that `prop = value` is not allowed in either syntax, JS object declaration nor JSON.

A description of the full JSON spec is [here](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) if you're interested.

### Manipulating JS Data

You asked what the best option code-wise is to add data to this JSON. Since JSON is just a format, it's not actually super relevant here, since it's primarily used for data storage and transport, and not for manipulation.

To work with data stored as JSON in Javascript, you can parse it in with the [`JSON.parse(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method, which will read a JSON string and return an equivalent Javascipt object. You can then use standard object/ array manipulation methods and techniques on that resulting object, in this case using [`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) to add a new recipe onto the array.

Answer (score 1):

I think propably the function you are looking for is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push, for example

```
recipeBook.recipes.push({
        name: 'Soup',
        ingredients:
        [
            {
                ingredientNam: 'Water',
                requiredAmount: 1
            },
            {
                ingredientName: 'Potatoes',
                requiredAmount: 4
            }
        ] 
    })
```

And for new ingredients it would be

```
recipeBook.recipes[0].ingredients.push(
            {
                ingredientName: 'Salt',
                requiredAmount: 1
            }
    )
```

I would recomend you to use the name of the recipe as the key in the recipes, I mean:

```
var recipeBook = 
{
    recipes: 
    {
        Spaghetti:
        {
            ingredients: 
            [
                {
                    ingredientName: 'Pasta',
                    requiredAmount: 1,
                },
                {
                    ingredientName: 'Tomato Sauce',
                    requiredAmount: 1,
                }
            ]
        },
        Cereal:
        {
            ingredients:
            [
                {
                    ingredientName: 'Cereal Box',
                    requiredAmount: 1
                },
                {
                    ingredientName: 'Milk',
                    requiredAmount: 1
                }
            ] 
        }
    }
}
```

This helps to get the recipe as

```
var spaghettiRecipe = recipeBook.recipes.Spaghetti
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code to add data to the object

```js
//add recipe
recipeBook.recipes.push(newRecipe);

//add ingredient to recipe by name
var recipe = recipeBook.recipes.find(r => r.name == recipeName);
if (recipe) recipe.ingredients.add(newIngredient);
```

Also your Cereal object is using `ingredientName = 'Cereal Box',` which is invalid javascript syntax. You need to use `:`  as in your spaghetti object.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating an object involves creating an object programmatically. I'm simplifying the code to make it easy:

```
var book = {}

function Recipe(name, ingredients) {
  this.name = name;
  this.ingredients = ingredients;
}

// instantiate it
var chicken_teriyaki = new Recipe('Teriyaki', ['new one', 'two', 'three'])
var fried_chicken = new Recipe('Fried Chicken', ['chicken', 'potato starch', 'oil'])


// add to book
book.chicken_teriyaki = chicken_teriyaki;
book.fried_chicken = fried_chicken;

// update recipe
book.chicken_teriyaki.ingredients.push('another yummy')

// view result
console.log('the book', book);
```